# How to access the elements in the set returned by an Alloy function?

Tags: function, get, return, alloy

I have an Alloy function in my model like:

```
fun whichFieldIs[p:Program, fId:FieldId, c:Class] : Field{
     {f:Field | f in c.*(extend.(p.classDeclarations)).fields && f.id = fId}    
}
```

This function is working in my model and can return a set of elements such as:
{Field$0, Field$1}
although the function return is not "set Field". I already saw this through the Alloy evaluator tool (available in alloy4.2.jar). What i am trying to do is getting the first element of this set in another predicate, for instance:

```
pred expVarTypeIsOfA[p:Program, exprName:FieldId, mClass:Class, a:ClassId]{

    let field = whichFieldIs[p, exprName, mClass],
         fieldType = field[0].type 
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Even when i change the return of the function to "set Field", the error "This expression failed to be typechecked" appears. I only want to get the first element of a set returned by a function, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Does the order really matter in that case? If so, you should take a look at this: [seq](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/seq.html)

> In the following example, for each person p, "p.books" is a sequence
>   of Book:
>
> ```
> sig Book { }
>   sig Person {
>       books: seq Book
>   }
> ```
>
> ...So if s is a sequence of Book, then the first element is s[0]...

`seq` is now a reserved word, but is nothing more than a relation `Int -> Elem`.

---

If it does not matter, you could use an adequate quantifier, e.g.:

```
pred expVarTypeIsOfA[p:Program, exprName:FieldId, mClass:Class, a:ClassId]{

    some field: whichFieldIs[p, exprName, mClass] | {
         field.type ...
    }
}
```

Comment: how to add element to seq. for me s.add[bk] is not working (here bk:Book)